# Excel creating a histogram through a data range with live data

Tags: excel, countif

I seem to be having an issue with Excel's built in functions.
I am running a what if analysis through a series of processes and that outputs 1000 different possible outcomes from V:04 to V:1003.

I was happy to achieve this as I have no experience with excels monte carlo analysis. My next task is to plot the data on a histogram, which I have achieved through Excel's data analysis tool. This however is the issue because the data analysis tool creates a frequency table to build the chart and hence does not allow to be updated when I re-run the what if analysis.

I have attempted creating my own chart with the same intervals through the data however am getting no results from the following functions (just 0 in each cell).

1) `=COUNTIF(V$4:V$1003,">=H74")-COUNTIF(V$4:V$1003,"<H75")`

2) `=COUNTIFS(V$4:V$1003,">=H74",V$4:V$1003,"<=H75")`

With H74:H104 containing the intervals for the chart.

Is there a known issue when using a data table and countifs?